# Angular2 Pagination not working

Tags: pagination, angular

I am using angular 2 beta. I am also using ng2 boostrap for showing pagination.
But I am getting an error `EXCEPTION: Template parse errors: The pipe 'paginate' could not be found`.

Here is my code:

Below showing is the .ts file in which I am dynamically loading my data in the table. Also I have included pagination directives from ng-bootsrap.

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Input} from 'angular2/core';
import {pagination, tableContent} from './interface';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/common';
import {PAGINATION_DIRECTIVES} from './ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';


@Component({
    selector: 'table-content',
    template: `
         <pagination [totalItems]="totalItems" [itemsPerPage]='2' (pageChanged)="pageChanged($event)" [(ngModel)]="currentPage" [maxSize]="maxSize" class="pagination-sm" [boundaryLinks]="true"></pagination>
         <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="#i of tablecontents" >
               <td class="text-centre">
                   <div class="rm-checkbox">
                       <input type="checkbox" id="" name="" value="1" tabindex="109">
                   </div>
               </td>
               <td>{{i.name}}</td>
               <td>{{i.email}}</td>
               <td>{{i.type}}</td>
               <td>{{i.content}}</td>
               <td>{{i.priority}}</td>
               <td>{{i.TTL}}</td>
           </tr>
        </tbody>`,
    directives: [PAGINATION_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class tablecontent implements OnInit {

    constructor() {
        this.name = 'Rules';
        this.ruleCount = 100;
        this.tablecontents = 'table.json'
        this.totalItems = tablecontents.length;
        this.bigTotalItems = tablecontents.length;
        this.currentPage = 4;
        this.maxSize = 5;
        this.bigCurrentPage = 1;
    }
    perPageCounts: perPageCount[] = [
        { text: '10', value: 1 },
        { text: '25', value: 2 },
        { text: '50', value: 3 },
        { text: '100', value: 4 }
    ];


    private setPage(pageNo: number): void {
        this.currentPage = pageNo;
    };

    private pageChanged(event: any): void {
        console.log('Page changed to: ' + event.page);
        console.log('Number items per page: ' + event.itemsPerPage);
    };
}
```

Could somebody please help

Answer (score 3):

Another option is a custom pagination service instead of ng2 bootstrap, I just posted [this pagination example](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/08/23/Angular-2-Pagination-Example-with-Logic-like-Google.aspx) which uses logic like google search results.

**PagerService** that handles the pagination logic:

```
import * as _ from 'underscore';

export class PagerService {
    getPager(totalItems: number, currentPage: number = 1, pageSize: number = 10) {
        // calculate total pages
        var totalPages = Math.ceil(totalItems / pageSize);

        var startPage, endPage;
        if (totalPages <= 10) {
            // less than 10 total pages so show all
            startPage = 1;
            endPage = totalPages;
        } else {
            // more than 10 total pages so calculate start and end pages
            if (currentPage <= 6) {
                startPage = 1;
                endPage = 10;
            } else if (currentPage + 4 >= totalPages) {
                startPage = totalPages - 9;
                endPage = totalPages;
            } else {
                startPage = currentPage - 5;
                endPage = currentPage + 4;
            }
        }

        // calculate start and end item indexes
        var startIndex = (currentPage - 1) * pageSize;
        var endIndex = Math.min(startIndex + pageSize - 1, totalItems - 1);

        // create an array of pages to ng-repeat in the pager control
        var pages = _.range(startPage, endPage + 1);

        // return object with all pager properties required by the view
        return {
            totalItems: totalItems,
            currentPage: currentPage,
            pageSize: pageSize,
            totalPages: totalPages,
            startPage: startPage,
            endPage: endPage,
            startIndex: startIndex,
            endIndex: endIndex,
            pages: pages
        };
    }
}
```

**AppComponent** that uses the pager service:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import * as _ from 'underscore';

import { PagerService } from './_services/index'

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private pagerService: PagerService) { }

    // dummy array of items to be paged
    private dummyItems = _.range(1, 151);

    // pager object
    pager: any = {};

    // paged items
    pagedItems: any[];

    ngOnInit() {
        // initialize to page 1
        this.setPage(1);
    }

    setPage(page: number) {
        if (page < 1) {
            return;
        }

        // get pager object from service
        this.pager = this.pagerService.getPager(this.dummyItems.length, page);

        // get current page of items
        this.pagedItems = this.dummyItems.slice(this.pager.startIndex, this.pager.endIndex + 1);
    }
}
```

**AppComponent HTML** that displays paged items and pager controls:

```
<div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="text-center">
            <h1>Angular 2 - Pagination Example with logic like Google</h1>

            <!-- items being paged -->
            <div *ngFor="let item of pagedItems">Item {{item}}</div>

            <!-- pager -->
            <ul *ngIf="pager.pages.length" class="pagination">
                <li [ngClass]="{disabled:pager.currentPage === 1}">
                    <a (click)="setPage(1)">First</a>
                </li>
                <li [ngClass]="{disabled:pager.currentPage === 1}">
                    <a (click)="setPage(pager.currentPage - 1)">Previous</a>
                </li>
                <li *ngFor="let page of pager.pages" [ngClass]="{active:pager.currentPage === page}">
                    <a (click)="setPage(page)">{{page}}</a>
                </li>
                <li [ngClass]="{disabled:pager.currentPage === pager.totalPages}">
                    <a (click)="setPage(pager.currentPage + 1)">Next</a>
                </li>
                <li [ngClass]="{disabled:pager.currentPage === pager.totalPages}">
                    <a (click)="setPage(pager.totalPages)">Last</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

More details and a working demo are available on [this post](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/08/23/Angular-2-Pagination-Example-with-Logic-like-Google.aspx).

Comment: I tried to follow this, and while the post is good I have issues getting it to work on a real data from a web service.  The pager works OK, but the ngFor displays all of the items returned from the web service (and placed in the array)

Comment: You need to wait for the data to be returned from the server before calling setPage(1). I've just updated the post and plunk to show how it works with data from a web service - http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/08/23/angular-2-pagination-example-with-logic-like-google

Answer (score 2):

Pipes need to be added to `pipes: [MyPipe]`. Your `tablecontent` component doesn't provide a `pipes:` parameter for `paginate`.

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html

Comment: I don't use ng2-bootstrap and in the one I found (https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=pagination&type=Code), I wasn't able to find anything named `paginate`. Can you point me to where you found this pipe should exist?

Comment: Hi, I have changed my Code without using pipes and all.. But now I dodnt know how can I relate my pagination with data. Can you please chk the url http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#pagination and tell me how we can dynamically load data with it

Comment: Your code still contains `| paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: 1 }"`.  Use `Http` service and fetch them from wherever you need and assign them to `this.tablecontents`. Besides that, I'm not sure what you mean by "dynamically load data"

Comment: I'm lost. Your code still contains `| paginate ...`. You didn't provide additional info where or how you want to get additional data or what the current problem is.

Comment: No Sir... I am not using `| paginate`

Comment: Now the problem is I am having the pagination HTMl and content. But content is not loading in pagination (Full content is showing in the page itself)

Comment: Checkout PrimeNG DataTable Paginator http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatablepaginator

Answer (score 1):

Download that source program from [github](https://github.com/michaelbromley/ng2-pagination). Next look into the src folder. There will be two files:

1. pagination-service.ts
2. paginate-pipe.ts

Copy the two files into your project. Next import them into app.module.ts. (The documentation in github is not complete.)

Comment: Thanks, actually it is an old post. I have fixed the issue. I dont remeber it now. Anyway thanks